# how to display the buttons in an accordion ( in a modal )

Tags: angularjs

My problem is:

In the modal I has an accordion with a form,

1- When I click on the **Next** button I have to fill in the input fields to open the next step .

2 - When I open the next step the **next** button disappears and the **prev** and **save** buttons appear.

But when I click on **One** step the accordion opens and closes two accordion but the buttons do not disappear and conversely when I click on the **Two** accordion.

How to make the buttons change when I click on accordions ?

Thank you in advance for all your answers.

My example : http://plnkr.co/edit/HMSBYTw1BgDakH3nXqw2?p=preview

HTML :

```
<form ng-submit="submit(myform)" name="myform" novalidate>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="cancel()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
      <uib-accordion-group is-open="status.isFirstOpen">
        <uib-accordion-heading>
          first step
        </uib-accordion-heading>
        <label>firstname</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="firstname" required>
      </uib-accordion-group>
      <uib-accordion-group is-open="status.isSecondOpen" is-disabled="status.isSecondDisabled">
        <uib-accordion-heading>
          second step
        </uib-accordion-heading>
        <label>lastname</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="lastname" required>
      </uib-accordion-group>
    </uib-accordion>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button ng-show="!viewNext" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="next()">Next</button>
    <button ng-show="viewNext" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
    <button ng-show="viewNext" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="prev()">prev</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

App.js :

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
 $scope.oneAtATime = true;

  $scope.status = {
    isFirstOpen: true,
    isSecondOpen: false,
    isSecondDisabled: true
  };

  $scope.next = function() {
    if ($scope.myform.firstname.$valid) {
      $scope.status = {
        isSecondOpen: true,
        isFirstOpen: false,
        isSecondDisabled: false
      };
       $scope.viewNext = true;
    }
  };

  $scope.prev = function() {
    $scope.status = {
      isSecondOpen: false,
      isFirstOpen: true
    };
   $scope.viewNext = false;
  };

  $scope.save = function() {
    if($scope.myform.$valid) {
      alert('Save and Valid !');
       $uibModalInstance.dismiss('close');
    }
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Comment: I dont understand your problem. Please elaborate.

Comment: yes , I will explain @RahulDesai what t is relatively simple:

when you click on the first link step = _button next_
when you click on the second link step = _prev and save button_

**But this is not the case on the link looks as examples.**

Comment: It is working for me. I think you are not giving any `firstname` in the modal.

Comment: The `firstname` is mandatory in your case.

Comment: @RahulDesai, 
Could you do me a plunker to show me that it works with you .

Comment: Your Plunkr itself works! I dint had to change anything.